# How to access controls and variables, across Class and Code-behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, scope, code-behind

i have ASP.NET page, its code-behind, and a Class file:

- **Folder1/page.aspx (asp.net page)**, it contains a `label`:

```asp
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

- **Folder1/page.aspx.vb (code-behind)**, it calls connection.vb like this:

```vb
    Dim x As New Connection
    Protected Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    x.checkusernameExists(TextBoxUsername.Text)
    ' I try to access `Boolean variable` Flag from Class file but I can't.
    End Sub
```

- **App_Code/connection.vb (a class file that i created)**:

```vb
    Public Class Connection
       Public Sub checkusernameExists(ByVal username1 As String)
       Dim flag as Boolean
       ' I try to access here `Label1.text` & `Label1.visible` to work on it but I can't.
       End Sub
    End Class
```

### My Questions

1 - **How can I access the `Label1` from the `ASP.NET page` in `Connection.vb`?**

2 - **How can I access the `Boolean variable` from `Connection.vb` in `page.aspx.vb`** (code behind)**?**

I am really stuck in this.
Thank you.

Comment: ok thank you for removing C# tag.

Answer (score 2):

Use (public) properties or method parameters.

You have to ask yourself following: why should a class that is responsible for a connection(i assume to database) have access to your GUI at all? Don't hardlink different layers with each other, otherwise you won't be able to use them alone.

I would suggest to let the connection class do it's work and that is not to modify your frontend. Instead the controller (the aspx page) should manage it's GUI and call the connection class, using the return value to determine what to do next with the `Label`.

So return a `Boolean` to indicate if the user is valid:

```
Public Class Connection
   Public Shared Function checkusernameExists(ByVal username1 As String)As Boolean
       Dim userExists As Boolean
       ' acces db to check if the username exists '
       Return userExists 
   End Sub
End Class
```

in your page:

```
Protected Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    Dim userExists As Boolean = Connection.checkusernameExists(TextBoxUsername.Text)
    Label1.Visible = userExists 
    If Label1.Visible Then Label1.Text = "Hello again " & TextBoxUsername.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Time for your explanation, it is really meaningful. I also understand that instead of get,set we can use a Public Shared Function and return a result, and then work on the result in the page code as you mentioned. It seems that the code however is not working for me currently, i might have missed something. I will post back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Function to return value and pass label as parameter.

```
Public Function SaveChanges(ByRef Label1 As Label, ByVal username1 As String) As Boolean
{
    Return True
}
```

It would be better if you pass the label properties to function instead of passing the object of label as it couple up two classes.

Comment: not a good way to access form level control creates indirect dependency between View and DataAccessLayer also violates Tell Don't Ask concept.

Comment: Thank you Adil, I don't quite understand, did you mean that I can use a Function in the Class file and return its result to the Sub in code behind file? just like Tim's answer?

Answer (score 1):

make flag as property and set this property in checkusernameExists function

```
 Public Class Connection

   Public Property  Flag as Boolean 
   Public Sub checkusernameExists(ByVal username1 As String)

    // set flag here
     Flag = True // or whateever value returned from the database
   ' I try to access here `Label1.text` & `Label1.visible` to work on it but I can't.
   End Sub
End Class
```

and access this instance level property in page.aspx.vb file

```
Dim x As New Connection
Protected Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
x.checkusernameExists(TextBoxUsername.Text)
Label1.Visible= x.Flag;
' I try to access `Boolean variable` Flag from Class file but I can't.
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Saurabh, so this is how i can access an object from a class, by using Property instead of Variable, I couldn't know without your help.